# Return unique mongo document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection. Below are the sample documents

```
{
"bannerUserSessionId" : "565269c7d52ece855050b3b7bd4ae8d6f52161871394e2d312c340a086f93314",
"bannerId" : "&lt;String&gt; kitchen-chimneys||1488286849020|HP|PromoBanner4",
"bannerEventLabel" : "&lt;String&gt; kitchen-chimneys",
"bannerPage" : "HP",
"bannerWidget" : "PromoBanner4",
"bannerClickTimestamp" : "Mar 04, 2017 15:05:56 PM"
}
{
"bannerUserSessionId" : "565269c7d52ece855050b3b7bd4ae8d6f52161871394e2d312c340a086f93314",
"bannerId" : "&lt;String&gt; kitchen-   chimneys||1488286849020|HP|PromoBanner4",
"bannerEventLabel" : "&lt;String&gt; kitchen-chimneys",
"bannerPage" : "HP",
"bannerWidget" : "PromoBanner4",
"bannerClickTimestamp" : "Mar 04, 2017 15:06:19 PM"
}
```

Is it possible to query mongodb in such a way that I'll get unique document as above two documents are same except different timestamp object?

So I want only one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `$group` by keys and pick the `$first` timestamp value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "bannerUserSessionId": "$bannerUserSessionId",
            "bannerId": "$bannerId",
            "bannerEventLabel": "$bannerEventLabel",
            "bannerPage": "$bannerPage"
        },
        "bannerClickTimestamp": {
            $first: "$bannerClickTimestamp"
        }
    }
}])
```